# Reshape error tensorflow RNN

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I am not able to get past an issue with my code. I keep getting the following error message when I run my code:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-cdb1929785d0> in <module>()
    108         tf.reset_default_graph()
    109 
--> 110 train_neural_network(x)

<ipython-input-1-cdb1929785d0> in train_neural_network(x)
     93                 end = i+batch_size
     94                 batch_x = np.array(X_train[start:end])
---> 95                 batch_x = batch_x.reshape((batch_size,n_chunks,chunk_size))
     96                 batch_y = np.array(y_1Hot_train.eval()[start:end])
     97 

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 784 into shape (10,28,28)
```

My dataset is a (88041, 784) array, of which I have a batch size of 10. When I take the line 95 and run it standalone I don't get any errors, the reshape occurs without fail.

For e.g. outside of tensorflow, this code segment works:

```
batch_x = np.array(X_train[0:10])
batch_x = batch_x.reshape((batch_size,n_chunks,chunk_size))
batch_x.shape # returns a shape of (10, 28, 28)
```

So I'm not sure why tensorflow keeps throwing the error. If you might have a better idea I'd greatly appreciate it.

The tf.sessions part is:

```
 with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for epoch in range (hm_epochs):
        epoch_loss = 0
        itere = int(X_train.shape[0]/batch_size)
        last = 0
        add = 1
        batch_size = 10
        i=0
        while i < len(X_train):
            start = i
            end = i+batch_size
            batch_x = np.array(X_train[start:end])
            batch_x = batch_x.reshape((batch_size,n_chunks,chunk_size))
            batch_y = np.array(y_1Hot_train.eval()[start:end])

            _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: batch_x,
                                                          y: batch_y})
            epoch_loss += c
            i+=batch_size
        sess_end = time.time() - start_time
```

The code is here: https://gist.github.com/makark/bab1cd6a80667226d0aff35f637463b0

Comment: `(10, 28, 28)` is 7840, an order of magnitude higher than 784. You're also using a batch size of 10. Complete stab in the dark (as I'm not sure what you're trying to do): `batch_x = batch_x.reshape((1,n_chunks,chunk_size))`

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this, it seems the issue was that I was using a dataset with size of (88041, 784) that could not be factored equally by 10 (batch_Size). It seems that in the last iteration of the loop, 1 sample was being left behind and causing the error. I removed the last sample from X_train and now it works...

Answer (score 0):

You are not feeding the  correct data batch, the size of your data 784, but in order to have shape `(10,28,28)` you need to have 7840, so 10 more examples (I guess from what you posted).

My guess is that you are feeding `X_train[0]`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reshaping `X_train` before you enter the training loop, rather than reshaping during each batch:

```
...
X = X1.values.astype(np.float32)
X = X.reshape(-1, 28, 28)
...
```

If you want to think of your training data as 28x28 matrices, it makes sense to do the reshaping as soon as possible. It will also make debugging easier down the line.